# How to limit Visibility of a popup menu only to a certain Project Type?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

I am using menuContributions+popup to show a context menu in my plugin.xml. I need to limit it's visibility only to

1. certain type of Project(e.g. Dynamic Web Project) (Menu should appear on right click of only parent project folder) and
2. a particular folder(e.g Web Content) and it's sub folders inside the Project Folder structure.

I was able to achieve the 1) condition to some extent by using

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=additions">
            <command
                label="Web Wiz"
                commandId="commandId"
                icon="icons/sample.gif">
               <visibleWhen>
                  <with  variable="selection">
                            <iterate ifEmpty="false"
                        operator="or">
                     <instanceof
                           value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
                  </iterate>
                  </with>
               </visibleWhen>
            </command>
        </menuContribution>
```

but it appears for all kinds of projects...I need to limit it to only a **Dynamic Web Project**, so what should I add to meet this requirement in plugin.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add a propertyTester that will test your project type.
2. Use that tester in the visibleWhen

You can read about property-tester at the eclipse help, or at the extension help itself :)

EDIT - Check this one out as well - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions#Property_Testers (especially the ResourcePropertyTester, which can provide you a built-in implementation that you can use)

Comment: <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">            <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"                   value="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature"/>            </adapt> did the trick  for a Web Project Type, I could get the nature of a particular project from the .project file of a project.

Comment: I used property Testers for my 2nd condition and was able to do the necessary checks.

Answer (score 2):

For the second condition:

```
<test   forcePluginActivation="true"
            property="testWizard.propertyTester.checkFolder"
             value="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature"
     </test>
```

is the reference to the property tester , which can be defined as

---

```
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
     <propertyTester          
        class="testwizard.wizards.MyPropTester"
           id="MyPropTesterFolder"
           namespace="testWizard.propertyTester"
           properties="checkFolder"
           type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
     </propertyTester>
```

---

then the kind of folder and it's subfolders can be tested as below in

```
package testwizard.wizards;

import org.eclipse.core.expressions.PropertyTester;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;

public class MyPropTester extends PropertyTester{

    @Override
    public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args,
            Object expectedValue) {

        IFolder folder=(IFolder)receiver;
        String folderPath=folder.getProjectRelativePath().toString();
        String arr[]=folderPath.split("/");     
        try {
            if(folder.getProject().hasNature(expectedValue.toString()))
            {
                if(arr[0].equals("XYZ"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=additions">
  <command
            label="Web Wiz"
            commandId="commandId"
            icon="icons/sample.gif">
    <visibleWhen>
      <with variable="selection">
        <iterate operator="and" ifEmpty="false">
           <test 
                  property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature" 
                  value="your-project-nature" />
        </iterate>
     </with>
    </visibleWhen>
</command>
<menuContribution>
```

Comment: NOTE: The above `<test>` doesn't work well with the `Package Explorer`. You can use `<test property="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.hasProjectNature" args="your-project-nature"/>` for all the navigators I've seen.